# how to get the _really_ last frame of a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, frame

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -sseof -X -i ergo.mp4 -vsync 0 -q:v 31 -update true -vframes 1 last.png
```

to get the last frame and changed X from 1 to 3 to 5. And this gives different pictures depending on X. Can anyone explain this? In my opinion the result should always be the same, right?

Comment: `-vframes 1` leads ffmpeg to stop after exporting the image at `EOF - X` time.

Answer (score 0):

From the post
[Extract final frame from a video using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795047/extract-final-frame-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg) :

> Use
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i file -vsync 0 -q:v 31 -update true out.jpg
> ```
>
> `-sseof` seeks from the end - I've used a value of 3, to account for
> files with longer audio streams.
>
> `-update` is an image2 muxer option which tells ffmpeg to overwrite
> the output file.
>
> So the last time the output will be overwritten is when the last frame
> is processed.